# Как устрнаить ошибку в django PasswordResetForm

Tags: python, django

Новичок в django, хочу сделать сброс пароля через email. Но выдает ошибку

> SMTPAuthenticationError at /password_reset (535, b'5.7.8 Username and
> Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
> c12-20020a05651c014c00b0024f3d1daeaasm1496274ljd.50 - gsmtp')

views.py:

```
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if password_reset_form.is_valid():
            data = password_reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            associated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=data))
            if associated_users.exists():
                for user in associated_users:
                    subject = "Password Reset Requested"
                    email_template_name = "authenticate/password_reset_email.txt"
                    c = {
                        "email": user.email,
                        'domain': '127.0.0.1:8000',
                        'site_name': 'Website',
                        "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                        "user": user,
                        'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                        'protocol': 'http',
                    }
                    email = render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
                    try:
                        send_mail(subject,
                                  email,
                                  settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                                  [user.email],
                                  fail_silently=False)
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                    return redirect("main:password_reset_done")
    else:
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="authenticate/password_reset_form.html",
                  context={"password_reset_form": password_reset_form})
```

urls.py:

```
path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
    template_name='authenticate/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset/<uibd64>/<token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='authenticate/password_reset_confirm.html')),
path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
    template_name='authenticate/password_reset_complete.html')),
path("password_reset", views.password_reset_request, name="password_reset")
```

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "Мой аккаунт"            # (ошибок нет)
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Пароль от аккаунта' # (ошибок нет)
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

В инете погуглил, советуют перейти [сюда](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) и разрешить вход. Но эта функция уже недоступна.
Скиньте ссылку где можно об этом почитать..

Comment: Возможно не лучший вариант но решил это так https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте в качестве ответа ссылку на сторонний ресурс.

Comment: Правда это пока не ответ, а комментарий...